# Spring Boot JMS listener won't deploy on EAP 7.3 (JBoss/Wildfly)

Tags: spring-boot, jboss, wildfly, spring-jms

I'm trying to deploy on EAP 7.3 (ex JBoss, commercial release of Wildfly) an JMS listener like below:

```
    ...
    @JmsListener(destination = "${jms.destination.name}")
    public void onMessage(final Message msg) throws JMSException {
      logger.info("*** MessageReceiver.onMessage(): got message {}", ((TextMessage) msg).getText());
    }
    ...
```

Deploying it on the app server I get the following warning:

```
2021-06-03 15:57:45,836 WARN  [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] (DefaultMessageListenerContainer-7) Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'jms.queue.BanQ' - trying to recover. Cause: There is no queue with name jms.queue.BanQ
```

The deployment gets stuck and the warning above is displayed continuously, every couple of seconds.

So what seems to happen is that the mention queue doesn't exist. However, looking in the console I can see that:

[image: console]

So, as shown in the figure above, the queue named jms.queue.Bank exists. What might be the problem here ?

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Kind regards,

Seymour

Comment: How do you connect to the broker ? jms.queue is the legacy prefix, you should look for BanQ

Comment: Yeah, this did the trick, thanks